# Как работает программа расчета факториала java?

Tags: java, рекурсия, факториал

Разбираю программу которая считает факториал и не понимаю как она работает.

Я это понимаю так, что `result = (5-1)*5 = 20`, то есть у меня результат 20.
Как программа выходит на результат 120? Объясните пожалуйста популярно, пошагово...

```
class Recursia2 {

    int factR(int n) {
        int result;

        if (n == 1) return 1;
        else result = factR(n - 1) * n;
        return result;
    }
}

class Recursion2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Recursia2 f = new Recursia2();
        System.out.println("Факториал 5 равен " + f.factR(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: факториал(5!): 1*2*3*4*5 = 120, так что все правильно

Comment: Пошагово объясняет отладчик с кнопочкой F11 (или какая там в джаве для step into).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно понимаете. Не `result = (5-1)*5` , а `result = factR(5-1)*5`.

Потом следует `result = factR(5-1-1)*(5-1)*5` и т.д. пока не дойдёт до `factR(1)`, после чего результат вычислится (`1*(5-1-1-1)*(5-1-1)*(5-1)*5`) и будет выдан.

Comment: А почему она работает как цикл если это не цикл?

Comment: Она работает как ресурсия, а не как цикл.

Answer (score 3):

Факториа́л — функция, определённая на множестве неотрицательных целых чисел. Название происходит от лат. factorialis — действующий, производящий, умножающий; обозначается n!, произносится эн факториа́л. Факториал натурального числа n определяется как произведение всех натуральных чисел от 1 до n включительно.

Т.е. факториал 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120

Что происходит в Вашем коде?

Функция factR вызывает себя же, только с n - 1, пока не дойдет до 1.

Уменьшение n:

```
else result = factR(n - 1) * n;
```

Условие выхода из рекурсии:

```
if (n == 1) return 1;
```

Таким образом, число n уменьшается до тех пор, пока не будет соблюдено условие выхода из рекурсии(число n не станет единицей).

Получается, что при каждом шаге функция умножает свой n на n "своего ребенка", что нас и приводит к формуле факториала:

n! = n * n - 1 * ... * 2 * 1.